# Siddhi CEP Pattern query performance

Tags: siddhi

Using Siddhi CEP standalone library's pattern query to detect non occurrence of an event periodically for every 5 minutes on 10k events. Observing memory gradually increasing. Any help on this why this happens?

[Memory footprint for non occurrence stream detection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Evkne.jpg)

Comment: Are you using Siddhi new version 3.0.0? If so can you please  do a profiling by using tool like "Java Flight Recorder" and share the recorded jfr file? Then we can observe where this memory leak happens. It can be client application or even it can be in Siddhi side. It would be appreciate if it is possible to share this sample where we can try to reproduce

Comment: Yes 3.0.1. I have shared heapdump and threaddump of one instance running for almost 3 days. Another instance running for 2 hours sharing jfr file.and also sample  [link] (https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0BxifNAFRuWpGOEk1Um1OQVZQd00&usp=sharing)

Comment: @TharikKanaka  
Yes 3.0.1. I have shared heapdump and threaddump of one instance running for almost 3 days. Another instance running for few hours sharing jfr file.and also sample [link] (https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0BxifNAFRuWpGOEk1Um1OQVZQd00&usp=sharing) .

Answer (score 1):

In your query you have not included within option for the pattern query. This will result in events which does not get matched for a pattern getting accumulated over time. That's why you observe a memory increase over time. Having a within statement will prompt Siddhi to drop events older than within time releasing memory.

Ex: From a1 -> b1 within 10 min

Comment: Hi @tishan Changed pattern query to include within statement, but still i see a sudden increase in memory after 6 hours. Running the sample for 10k entities continuously, shared the memory footprint image and sample code [link] (https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0BxifNAFRuWpGcGtWbHlXUVVIaWc&usp=sharing)